# HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler & HexDumpProxyBackendHandler

Tags: java, netty, nio

How can I modify the status code by HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler or HexDumpProxyBackendHandler class?
becase I want to change 302 status to 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dont want to write your own decoder use HttpResponseDecoder and HttpObject aggregator infront of backendHandler and modify the response states

Comment: THX for your answer, I setted HttpRequestDecoder for HDPFrontendHandler and HttpResponseEncoder for HDPBackendHandler. But occurs "unsupported message type: DefaultHttpRequest" Exception at ChannelRead of HDPFrontendHandler, Do u know why?

Comment: HDPhandlers accept bare bytebufs from what I remember so you will need to modify them. I suggest going through code for netty based proxies on github

Comment: One well-known HTTP proxy implementation is LittleProxy - https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy